# tensorflow Multiplying tensors of different shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow, If I had a tensors:

```
A = tf.fill([3,2,2],2) # shape [3,2,2]
B = tf.constant([1,2,3]) # shape [3]
```

How can I multiply them so that I get the resulting tensor with shape [3,2,2]?

```
[
  [ [2,2], [2,2] ],
  [ [4,4], [4,4] ],
  [ [6,6], [6,6] ]
]
```

My multiplication factors are simple here for demonstration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape `B` to `(3,1,1)` so that `A` and `B` have the same number of dimensions and then do multiplication. `tf.multiply` supports [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) so dimension with size `1` in `B` will be broadcasted and multiplied with all elements in corresponding dimension in `A`:

```
(A * tf.reshape(B, (3,1,1))).eval()

# array([[[2, 2],
#         [2, 2]],

#        [[4, 4],
#         [4, 4]],

#        [[6, 6],
#         [6, 6]]], dtype=int32)
```